# how to get document above average value in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

After grouping by device ID, I want to find the number of data with a numerical value greater than or equal to the average value of the data.

```js
doc = [
  { deviceId: 1, data: {temp:1} },
  { deviceId: 1, data: {temp:2} },
  { deviceId: 1, data: {temp:3} },
  { deviceId: 1, data: {temp:4} },
  { deviceId: 1, data: {temp:5} },
  { deviceId: 2, data: {temp:1} },
  { deviceId: 2, data: {temp:2} },
  { deviceId: 2, data: {temp:3} },
  { deviceId: 2, data: {temp:4} },
  { deviceId: 2, data: {temp:5} },
  { deviceId: 3, data: {temp:1} },
  { deviceId: 3, data: {temp:2} },
  { deviceId: 3, data: {temp:3} },
  { deviceId: 3, data: {temp:4} },
  { deviceId: 3, data: {temp:5} },
];
```

**"The desired result is"**

```js
result = aggregations :{
  clusters:{
    ...
    bucket:[
      { key:"1",
        doc_count: 5,
        avgData: {value: 3.0}
        above_avgDataValue : {
          doc_count : 2 //  === data.temp > 3 
        }
      }
    ]

  }
}
```

Below is the aggregation I tried

```js
_search {
  size:0,
  query:{
    bool:{
      filter:[
        terms:{deviceId:[1,2]}
      ]
    }
  },
  aggs:{
    cluster:{
      terms:{field:deviceId}
    },
    aggs:{
      "avgData" : {"avg": {"field":"temp"}}
    }
  }
};
```

please help

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You need to make 2 queries. One to compute the average, another to get the documents you want

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr;

I don't think this is possible with a single query.

But you could work around the issue by:

- Get the average per `deviceId`
- Get the number of doc above the average of `deviceId`

## Work around

To get the average per `deviceId` the following query should work.

```json
GET /73034730/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "avg_per_fields": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "deviceId",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "avg": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "data.temp"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you could do the following query

```json
GET /73034730/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "deviceId": "1"
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "data.temp": {
                    "gte": 3
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "deviceId": "2"
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "data.temp": {
                    "gte": 3.33333335
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "deviceId": "3"
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "data.temp": {
                    "gte": 3
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "avg_per_fields": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "deviceId",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which considering the dataset you have should give you

```json
{
...
"aggregations": {
    "avg_per_fields": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": 1,
          "doc_count": 3
        },
        {
          "key": 2,
          "doc_count": 3
        },
        {
          "key": 3,
          "doc_count": 3
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer.
The method you mentioned is sane, but doesn't seem to be scalable.
When there are a lot of devices (1000+) the bool query lines seem to increase.

Comment: Absolutely, this is not very scalable. But I have yet to find a better alternative.